# Python windows path regex

Tags: python, regex

I've spent the last two hours figuring this out. I have this string:

```
C:\\Users\\Bob\\.luxshop\\jeans\\diesel-qd\\images\\Livier_11.png
```

I am interested in getting `\\Livier_11.png`  but it seems impossible for me. How can I do this?

Comment: What's your code so far?

Comment: my first try was 'C:\\\\([^\\\\]+)_\\d+.png$'  but that did not work. then i tried [^C:\\\\Users\\\\Bob\\\\\.luxshop\\data\\jeans\diesel-qd\\\\images]\w+.png and it gives me  Livier_11.png. So i dont know how to get the \\ before the filename :( and between that i tried maybe ten to twenty different combinations without being lucky.

Comment: Unless there's a specific reason why you need to use Regex, I'd use `pathlib` instead. See my answer below for details and feel free to comment whether this helps there.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is a reason. The pattern is passed as an argument into another function and I don't think my colleagues will be happy with me if I change it tonight. But thank you for recommending pathlib :)

Comment: You can check my answer out anyways, I edited it and added a regex version ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd strongly recommend using the python `pathlib` module. It's part of the standard library and designed to handle file paths. Some examples:

```
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> p = Path(r"C:\Users\Bob\.luxshop\jeans\diesel-qd\images\Livier_11.png")
>>> p
WindowsPath('C:/Users/Bob/.luxshop/jeans/diesel-qd/images/Livier_11.png')
>>> p.name
'Livier_11.png'
>>> p.parts
('C:\\', 'Users', 'Bob', '.luxshop', 'jeans', 'diesel-qd', 'images', 'Livier_11.png')
>>> # construct a path from parts
...
>>> Path("C:\some_folder", "subfolder", "file.txt")
WindowsPath('C:/some_folder/subfolder/file.txt')
>>> p.exists()
False
>>> p.is_file()
False
>>>
```

**Edit:**

If you want to use regex, this should work:

```
>>> s = "C:\\Users\\Bob\\.luxshop\\jeans\\diesel-qd\\images\\Livier_11.png"
>>> import re
>>> match = re.match(r".*(\\.*)$", s)
>>> match.group(1)
'\\Livier_11.png'
>>>
```

Comment: This doesn't help if you're working with Windows paths on a Unix machine. `NotImplementedError: cannot instantiate 'WindowsPath' on your system`

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Yes, you can do it, but ensure to use `PurePath` instead of `Path`, the rest should be the same.

Answer (score 3):

**You can use this**

```
^.*(\\\\.*)$
```

> Explanation

- `^` - Anchor to start of string.
- `.*` - Matches anything except new line zero or time (Greedy method).
- `(\\\\.*)` - Capturing group. Matches `\\` followed  any thing except newline zero or more time.
- `$` - Anchor to end of string.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/DsFyF7/3)

**P.S** - For such kind of this you should use standard libraries available instead of regex.

Answer (score 2):

If you can clearly say that "\\" is a delimiter (does not appear in any string except to separate the strings) then you can say:

```
str = "C:\\Users\\Bob\\.luxshop\\jeans\\diesel-qd\\images\\Livier_11.png"
spl = str.split(“\\”) #split the string
your_wanted_string = spl[-1]
```

Please note this is a very simple way to do it and not always the best way! If you need to do this often or if something important depends on it use a library!
If you are just learning to code then this is easier to understand.

Comment: Just food for thought: this does not use any kind of regex. But you do not have to use regex since regex might be a bit hard to understand and might be a bit more resource hungry then a simple split. While I would not recommend to use something this simple in any commercial code (use a library), for learning the split operation is very easy to understand and to apply.

Comment: This is cool and this is how it should be done. cheers mate :)

Comment: Thanks for the flowers. However I believe your version does fit the question a bit better. I only saw the regex in the question to late.