# Extracting a word between two path separators that comes after a specific word

Tags: python, regex

I have the following path stored as a python string `'C:\ABC\DEF\GHI\App\Module\feature\src'` and I would like to extract the word `Module` that is located between words `\App\` and `\feature\` in the path name. Note that there are file separators `'\'` in between which ought not to be extracted, but only the string `Module` has to be extracted.

I had the few ideas on how to do it:

1. Write a RegEx that matches a string between `\App\` and `\feature\`
2. Write a RegEx that matches a string after `\App\` --> `App\\[A-Za-z0-9]*\\`, and then split that matched string in order to find the `Module`.

I think the 1st solution is better, but that unfortunately it goes over my RegEx knowledge and I am not sure how to do it.

I would much appreciate any help.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python windows path regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53710956/python-windows-path-regex)

Comment: Please take some time to familiarise yourself with the basics of Markdown and editing in the help. — Fixing the formatting of your question was quite a lot of work! (And I had to guess at your intentions.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regex you want is:

```
(?<=\\App\\).*?(?=\\feature\\)
```

Explanation of the regex:

- `(?<=behind)rest` matches all instances of `rest` if there is `behind` immediately before it. It's called a positive lookbehind
- `rest(?=ahead)` matches all instances of `rest` where there is `ahead` immediately after it. This is a positive lookahead.
- `\` is a reserved character in regex patterns, so to use them as part of the pattern itself, we have to escape it; hence, `\\`
- `.*` matches any character, zero or more times.
- `?` specifies that the match is not greedy (so we are implicitly assuming here that `\feature\` only shows up once after `\App\`).
- The pattern in general also assumes that there are no `\` characters between `\App\` and `\feature\`.

The full code would be something like:

```
str = 'C:\\ABC\\DEF\\GHI\\App\\Module\\feature\\src'
start = '\\App\\'
end = '\\feature\\'

pattern = rf"(?<=\{start}\).*?(?=\{end}\)"

print(pattern)                            # (?<=\\App\\).*?(?=\\feature\\)
print(re.search(pattern, str)[0])         # Module
```

A link on regex lookarounds that may be helpful: https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: Thank you for very detailed description of each Regular Expression in your pattern! That worked like a charm in my python code, and was just what I needed. The link for regex lookarounds is very useful as well!

Answer (score 2):

We can do that by `str.find` somethings like

```
str = 'C:\\ABC\\DEF\\GHI\\App\\Module\\feature\\src'
import re
start = '\\App\\'
end = '\\feature\\'

print( (str[str.find(start)+len(start):str.rfind(end)]))
print("\n")
```

output

```
Module
```

Answer (score 2):

Your are looking for groups. With some small modificatians you can extract only the part between   App and Feature.

```
(?:App\\\\)([A-Za-z0-9]*)(?:\\\\feature)
```

The brackets `(` `)` define a Match group which you can get by `match.group(1)`. Using `(?:foo)` defines a non-matching group, e.g. one that is not included in your result. Try the expression here: https://regex101.com/r/24mkLO/1

Comment: That is quite neat. I did not know you could group a RegEx like that. I tried your RegEx in a python, but `re.search` returns NULL --> `sw_module_name_regex = re.search(r'(?:App\\\\)([A-Za-z0-9]*)(?:\\\\feature)', element)`. I guess your RegEx not using the Python syntax? See https://regex101.com/r/24mkLO/1 it throws a pattern error "incomplete group structures" for the 2nd non-capturing group `(?<match>[A-Za-z0-9]*)`.